# USB JTAG script

Tags: usb, jtag

I need to write a script for interfacing Texas Instrument's RM48x via a JTAG-USB (Texas Instrument's XDS100v2) in order to achieve boundary scan since none of Texas Instrument's tools does that.

There are some tools out there for this but they are all really expensive and my project doesn't have the money for that.

Has anyone here tried it? Or at least does anyone here know where to start?

Comment: Is your problem in talking to the JTAG-USB or in interfacing it with the chip or...?

Comment: To tell you the truth .. everything hehehe.

Comment: The XDS100v2 comes with an FT232 USB JTAG converter, which means I probably need to interface with it via a Virtual Serial Port. Upo to that point no problem. The problem comes to the actual communication with the chip .. how can I achieve boundary scan? How do I start? How can I make them understand what's going on?